# Realm: Query with variable in Swift 2

Tags: swift, realm

absolute newbie-question: I have a model that consists of two objects in a Realm-database: Person and Dog. Person contains a list of Dogs. How can I query/filter for a list of dogs when the name of the Person is being handed over from a previous VC? For a tableView I need the query at the top of my VC-code. To access a single Person, I tried

```
personName: String! (derived from previous VC)     
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", personName)
let currentPerson = try! Realm().objects(Person).filter(predicate)
```

but I get

**Instance member 'personName' cannot be used on type 'dogsVC'**

What I want is simply list all the dogs of a specific person in a tableView.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to instantiate your predicate in `viewDidLoad` for example.
Or make it a computed property:

```
var predicate:NSPredicate {
    return NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", personName)
}
```

And that's because you need to wait for your class to initialize before using `self`.

Comment: Thanks! But this way `currentPerson` is not available for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier` for `currentPerson` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That doesn't surprise me, since it stays in the scope of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: ok, you need to declare it outside and only initialize in `viewDidLoad`